# Strange behaviour with command-line perl

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I have a file that I'm trying to modify using perl from the terminal in Ubuntu Linux (Natty).

The name of the file is vm.args and the first two lines are as follows:

```
## Name of the riak node
-name riak@127.0.0.1
```

I am trying to use perl to update the ip address. Below is my code:

```
riak_ip=`ifconfig eth1 | grep "inet addr" | cut -d ":" -f2 | cut -d " " -f1`
perl -0777 -i -pe "s/(\-name[\t ]*riak\@)[^\n]+/\1$riak_ip/g" vm.args
```

Let's assume the ip address I get is 10.181.106.32. The perl command gives me a result I can't understand. The resulting first two lines in the my file after I run the above in the terminal become:

```
## Name of the riak node
H.181.106.32
```

Which is the letter H and part of the ip address.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong and will appreciate some assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is Unix, right? You'll get better results if you put `perl`'s `-e` argument in single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @mob - except that he wants the env var `$riak_ip` to expand into the inline perl script.

Comment: `\1` is a regex pattern that matches the string captured by the first capture. It makes no sense to use it in a replacement expression. It is also the cause of your problems. Get rid of it! You should be using `$1`.

Comment: @ikegami It turns out you were right about that. `${1}` seems to be the better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work reliably:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe "s/(-name\\s*riak@).*/\${1}$riak_ip/g" vm.args
```

The "`\\1$riak_ip`" seems to cause some problems since perl was seeing it as "`\1172.20.2.136`" if `$riak_ip` was 172.20.2.136.  My guess is that the back reference to "1172" was causing some weirdness.  Anyway, switching to the `${1}` form removes the possibility for misinterpretation (pun intended).

Comment: `\117` is character 0117, which is character 0x4F, which is character 79, which is "O", which is ʟᴀᴛɪɴ ᴄᴀᴘɪᴛᴀʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ᴏ.

Comment: @D.Shawley Thanks a lot, this did the trick. I'll also take note of the `${1}` form you mentioned, I think I'm going to use that from now on. Cheers.

Comment: @tchrist I guess that explains why I was getting the letter H in my own result. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @tchrist, thanks much for figuring that one out.  I've been trying to figure out what was going on there.  I don't know why I didn't see the literal expansion of an octal constant in the string.  Nice Work.

Answer (score 1):

This really should all be done in Perl, which is much better at extracting data from text than shell script. Something like this should work, but I cannot test it at present.

```
perl -0777 -i -pe '($ip)=`ifconfig eth1`=~/inet addr:([\d.]+)/;s/-name\s+riak@\K[\d.]+/$ip/g;' vm.args
```

I would be grateful if someone could confirm whether this works OK. Beware that the `\K` construct in Perl regexes is a recent addition and may not be in any given installation of Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `\1` gets concatenated with the first IP octet. To make it work despite concatenation, the `${1}` syntax needs to be used and properly quoted. This works:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe "s/(\-name[\t ]*riak\@)[^\n]+/\${1}$riak_ip/g" vm.args
```

You might consider to use single quotes for the regex parts, to remove one layer of quoting:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/(-name[\t ]*riak@)[^\n]+/${1}'"$riak_ip"'/g' vm.args
```

(Edited/corrected according to comments, my previous suggestion was wrong.)

Comment: Escaping `\1` solves nothing, as the problem is that `$1` should be used there instead.

Comment: `\1` is the traditional/legacy syntax for `$1`. They are equivalent, given that perl actually gets to see one of them.

Comment: @jwodder - that's odd ... according to the perl docs and many years of convention, `\1` is quite acceptable - _"Absolute numbered groups were referred to using \1, \2, etc., and this notation is still accepted (and likely always will be)"_

Comment: +1 Running `riak_ip=12.34.56.78;echo "s/(\-name[\t ]*riak\@)[^\n]+/\1$riak_ip/g"` was insightful.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger I get the same result with your code suggestion

Comment: @D.Shawley: That paragraph has been rescinded in the `perlre` documentation for Perl v5.12. It is replaced with this warning ***Warning on \1 Instead of $1.*** *Some people get too used to writing things like: `$pattern =~ s/(\W)/\\\1/g;` This is grandfathered (for `\1` to `\9`) for the RHS of a substitute to avoid shocking the sed addicts, but it's a dirty habit to get into. That's because in PerlThink, the righthand side of an `"s///"` is a double-quoted string. `"\1"` in the usual double-quoted string means a control-A. The customary Unix meaning of `"\1"` is kludged in for `"s///"`.*

Comment: @D.Shawley Within a pattern, `\1` is the same as `\g{1}`.  But in a double-quoted string, it’s a `\cA`.

Comment: @jwodder, it hasn't been rescinded as much as it has been accepted as a legacy alternative.  The same text has existed in Perl for some time.  I do agree that `$1` is definitely the "Perl way" but I would not expect to see `\1` through `\9` go away since it is still the _"customary UNIX"_ RE replacement syntax used by sed, vi, and just about everywhere outside of Perl/Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use for the `\K` sequence (v5.10). And `[^\n]` is actually `.`, unless the `/s` modifier is used. No need for `/g` option unless you intend to replace the string several times.

```
perl -0777 -i -pe "s/\-name[\t ]*riak\@\K.+/$riak_ip/" vm.args
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be the correct regexp:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe "s/(-name\s*riak@)\S+/$1$riak_ip/g" vm.args
```

Result:

```
## Name of the riak node
10.181.106.32
```

Use `\s` for space characters, and `\S` (no space character) to match the whole IP address. In the replacement string, `$1` is used instead `\1`. `-` and `@` are not special, so there is no need to escape them, although there is nothing bad with them.

Comment: This is wrong. Your $1 gets interpreted by the shell before perl gets to see it. The OP wants to replace the IP address only, preserving the part before it.